# Itunes connect team not showing in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I was recently added to a team on Itunes connect in order for uploading an app to the store (they gave me admin role).

But for some reason, I can't see the team on Xcode (I have another team that is indeed visible on the team dropdown on Xcode).

Is there something I need to do manually in order for the team to show in my Xcode? I tried to delete my account from the Xcode preferences and then add it again, but no luck (still shows one team, while I should see two).

Any guidance will help tremendously, I have to admit I'm quite lost in all the provisioning profiles/certificates etc..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is also a "People" section in https://developer.apple.com/account, are you added as a developer (member/admin) in there too? If not, that is the problem. Adding you to iTunes Connect alone is not enough AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah I'm not on there (only showing one team), but can't I add myself as an admin on the other team? Or only the legal can do that? Or somebody else entirely? I'm so confused (´･_･`)

Comment: Someone who has agent or admin role in https://developer.apple.com/account/#/people can add you there.

Comment: Is there a new name for this people section?

Comment: @FullDecent, no it is still named as "people", and this is the url for the page: https://developer.apple.com/account/#/people